# Create the navigation bar in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigationbar, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I am creating my ***navigation bar*** in `viewDidLoad`. I saw in many sample codes that a ***navigation bar*** should be created in `viewWillAppear`. If my *view controller* is the *root view controller*, the ***navigation bar*** background image is not set. Else it seems to works normally. Is there any way that I can create the ***navigation bar*** *completely* and *only once* in the whole *life cycle* of the *view controller* and not in `viewWillAppear`?

**Current Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self initializeNavigationBar];
}
```

I do not want to do this in the `viewWillAppear`, as I present views. Closing these presented views, calls `viewWillAppear`. Thus, the ***navigation bar*** is **reinitialized**.

**The following code is what I'm *AVOIDING*:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [self initializeNavigationBar];
}
```

**Navigation Bar Creation Method:**

```
- (void)initializeNavigationBar
{
    navBar = [[ICANavBarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 44)];
    navBar.delegate = self;
    [navBar createViewWithTitle:StringForKey(@"company_short_title")];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:navBar];

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

    //iOS7 Bug fixation of Navigation Bar
    [navBar hideStatusBarOnViewController:self];

    [self.navBar enableEditButton:(imageView.layer.sublayers.count > 0)];
}
```

Comment: Are you setting your `rootViewController` to an `UINavigationController` in your `appDelegate`?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing that.

Comment: Some of your code would be helpful. What do you mean by "creating my navigation bar"? Are you calling `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`?

Comment: You clearly have code already so please share what you already have so we aren't guessing.

Comment: That code tells us nothing. What is the code behind `initializeNavigationBar`

Comment: Are you switching to a view controller which hides the navigation bar and then switching back and expecting the navigation bar to still be shown? If so, in `viewWillAppear` you need to set the navigation bar hidden value to `NO`.

Comment: The navigation bar is created and shown. Only the background image is not set.

Comment: I imagine you need to do `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]` in `viewWillAppear`.

Off the top of my head, the navigation bar is shared amongst all the view controllers below it. I am guessing the background image gets changed in other view controllers and therefore when this view controller is shown again, you have to tell it to reset the background image. `viewDidLoad` won't be called as technically the view is already loaded, its just appearing again.

Comment: Don´t forget to call super.  [super viewDidLoad] etc.